# How do i get a php program to check a drop down menu and only display an error when nothing is selected?

Tags: php

I am creating a form, everything works except this one thing. I have a drop down menu to select a country, and a php program using regular expressions to check the form for format. everything works except that one thing.

The array is:

```
$country = array (
    "select" => "",
    "us" => "United States",
    "ca" => "Canada",
    "mx" => "Mexico", );
```

The form code for the drop down is:

```
 if($field == "city") {
            echo "<div class='field'>";

            echo "<label for='country'>Country</label>
                    <select id='country' name='country'>";

                foreach ( $country as $select => $option)
                {
                    echo "<option value='$select'>$option</option>";
                }
```

My code is:

```
$country_patt = "(United States|Mexico|Canada)";

if (preg_match("/country/i",$field))
    {
        if(!preg_match($country_patt, $value))
        {   
            $error_array[] = "$select is invalid";  
        }
    }
```

I am sure it is an easy fix, but not finding it. :/

Comment: Why are you using a regex on the field name?

Comment: please provide us with all of your code, what you have provided does not give us enough information to help you out

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is your value of your select is going to be "select", "us", "ca", or "mx". Not the label.

Also, since you have a defined list to choose from, instead of:

```
if(!preg_match($country_patt, $value)) {...
```

You can do:

```
if(!array_key_exists($value, $country)) {...
```

Comment: Good catch, I didn't even pay attention to the select values.

Comment: I think it's important to note, that `$country` may not exist in the context of the second portion of PHP provided.

Comment: Thanks, and true, I just reused a variable in the question for clarity.  They'll have to determine for their specific case if the original `$country` variable is available, or if they have to copy it, or define it in some form.  But definitely worthy of noting.

Answer (score 0):

A small fix, is to add `OR` to the condition

by the way, regular expressions might be an overkill for this example :-)

```
$country_patt = "(United States|Mexico|Canada)";

if ("country"==$field)
    {
        if ((empty($value)) || (!preg_match($country_patt, $value)))
        {   
            $error_array[] = "$select is invalid";  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot easier to maintain would be arrays.

```
$countries = [ 'us', 'ca', 'mx' ];
if (!in_array($value, $countries)) {
  $error_array[] = "$select is invalid";
}
```

As CJ pointed out, your values of the HTML select will be us, ca, and mx.

Comment: Sidenote: `[ 'us', 'ca', 'mx' ]` assuming OP is PHP 5.4 >

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yeap, and hopefully (since 5.3 has been EOL for a little while now)

Comment: Yeah, just thought I'd make a mention of it ;-) I'd upvote, but no more left for today. I'll see you on the flipside ;-)

Comment: All voted out?  Guess you should have been a little more judgmental earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if the variable has been set with isset($select).

Like this...

```
if(isset($select)) {
  //Do action if $select has a value
} else {
  //Generate error
}
```

Reference:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php